# CI Codeigniter pagination without counting all results from db

Tags: php, codeigniter, optimization, pagination

i was wondering if anyone as a good idea or solution to use pagination without counting all records before splitting results

i mean when paginating with default CI library we must set total number of records, and this will be too huge for high amount of records don’t you think?

what if i have more then 500’000 records to be paginated?

so my idea was trying paginating using ranges somenthing like :

page 1 => query LIMIT 0,10

page 2 => query LIMIT 10,20

but i found many problems:

1) i anyway need to count all records to retrieve page numbers
2) how to save ranges ([1,10] [10,20] ... etc)?

thanks to anyone could help me

Comment: It should do that automatically. If you want to manually set the number of queryies, then set your $config[num_of_rows] = '500,000'. my syntax may be off but look for that in a pagianation tutorial.

Comment: I don't think pagination is going to do you much good with 500,000 records.  The goal is to make the data easier to digest but with that many records it's still going to be impossible to find what you are looking for.  You probably want to retrive a subset of the data before returning and paginating it.

Comment: I agree with Chris, do a search and paginate the results. This will make it more user-friendly

Comment: well thanks guys, i think the problem is that as i can see CI doesn't put limit in query by default or i'm mistaking?  cause once i enable output_profiler() i can see query and there is no limit inside ... so CI , guessing, is still retrieving and counting all results then split them by php? :/    hoping i'm mistaking

Comment: also i was wondering what about saving tot records number into a single db record?  so anytime i will not need to count 500K  records to retrieve the total which is just in a single db record..  maybe not good for db optimization? :P

Comment: why do you want get total records count ? you can just make 1 button "more" and load content like on facebook

Answer (score 1):

If you use your solution where you use a `LIMIT` to get each page, then use the [FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

It will give you **the amount of rows totally excluding the limit**. This way you don't need two queries where the first retrieves the specific range and the other one retrieves the total rows.

Comment: hi ancide,thanks for attention,   sincerily i'm thinking about how to NOT count anytime db total records before splitting them :P , have any idea? :P

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Have you even tried using the function I suggested?

Comment: yes i used man :) and that's really ok, what i'm trying to do is to NOT use a query COUNT for retrieving total records :P cause in 500K records will be really huge to count so i was trying looking at some other solution for retrieving total rows, somenthing  like saving all the times total rows in a single db record... but this should be not good for db optimization ... what you think? :P